# Jest Testing for React components

Tags: javascript, reactjs, jestjs, enzyme, mount

Hello below I have my navigation component

```
class Nav extends Component {
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
        anchorEl: null,
        layoutMode: 'desktop',
        value: tabs.findIndex(tab => {return tab.href === this.props.router.pathname; })
    };
}

render() {
    const { classes, authenticated, user } = this.props;
    const { anchorEl, value } = this.state;
    const open = Boolean(anchorEl);
    let firstLetter;
    if (user) {
        firstLetter = user.email.charAt(0);
    }
    return (
        <AppBar className={classes.appBar} position="static">
            <Toolbar className={classes.toolbar}>
                <img src="/static/images/Bluelight_Header_Bitmap.jpg" alt="blpd logo" className = {classes.logo}/>
                {authenticated && this.state.layoutMode ==='desktop' ? (
                    <Grid container
                        direction ="row"
                        justify="flex-end"
                        alignItems="center">
                        <div>
                            <Tabs id="Tab" value={value} onChange={this.handleChange}>
                                {tabs.map(tab => {
                                    return (<LinkTab key={tab.href} classes={{ root: this.props.classes.tabRoot }} label={tab.label} alt={tab.label} href={tab.href}/>);})}
                            </Tabs>
                        </div>
                    </Grid>
                ) : (
                    authenticated && <BurgerMenu/>
                )}
                <div style={{ marginLeft: 'auto' }}>
                    <IconButton
                        aria-owns={open ? 'menu-appbar' : undefined}
                        aria-haspopup="true"
                        onClick={this.handleMenu}
                        color="inherit"
                        alt="Icon Button"
                        aria-label="Login Button"
                        style={{margin: '5px'}}
                    >
                        {!authenticated ? <div></div> :
                            <AccountCircle/>
                        }
                    </IconButton>
                    <Menu
                        id="menu-appbar"
                        anchorEl={anchorEl}
                        anchorOrigin={{
                            vertical: 'top',
                            horizontal: 'right',
                        }}
                        transformOrigin={{
                            vertical: 'top',
                            horizontal: 'right',
                        }}
                        open={open}
                        onClose={this.handleClose}
                    >
                        {user && <MenuItem divider={true}>
                            <CardHeader
                                titleTypographyProps={{ variant:'title' }}
                                subheaderTypographyProps={{ variant:'body2' }}
                                avatar={<Avatar>{firstLetter}</Avatar>}
                                title={user.email}
                                subheader={user.email}

                            />
                        </MenuItem>}
                        <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>Profile</MenuItem>
                        <MenuItem onClick={this.handleClose}>My account</MenuItem>
                        {authenticated?
                            <a href='/auth/logout'><MenuItem>Logout</MenuItem></a>:
                            <a href='/auth'><MenuItem>Login</MenuItem></a>
                        }
                    </Menu>
                </div>
            </Toolbar>
        </AppBar>
    );    }}
```

I need to test this component, within my nav.test.js file i have the following code

```
describe('NavBar', () => {
  const intialState = {
    ui: { width: 1361 },
    auth: { authenticated: true }
  };

  let container;
  beforeEach(() => {
    container = mount(<Nav />);
  });

  it('should contain an AppBar', () => {
    expect(container.find(AppBar)).toHaveLength(1);
  });
});
```

However when running my tests i receive the following error [image]

Can anyone see where i am going wrong? I have tried to find the problem by reading documentation with Jest and mount seems to be the best option, however i am new to unit testing so this could be wrong. Thankyou

Comment: I would clean your test to the minimum possible, remove everything from the `Nav` except an empty `AppBar`, and try it. this will clean your question.

Answer (score 0):

This line:

```
container = mount(<Nav />);
```

...is throwing an error *while your component is rendering*.

The `beforeEach` ends up catching the error which allows your test to continue, but `container` is `undefined`.

When `Jest` starts running your test this line fails:

```
expect(container.find(AppBar)).toHaveLength(1);
```

...because `container` is `undefined` which causes your test to fail with that error message.

So that error really doesn't have anything to do with the real problem, the real problem is that your component is throwing an error as it renders.

Answer (score -1):

You should use `shallow` instead of `mount` .

```
beforeEach(() => {
    container = shallow(<Nav />);
  });
```

Comment: Yes, That's the point. Because you want to test each component independently. Shallow will just render the test components. Mount will render each an every component including all the children, which should not be the case.

Comment: The test clearly is about `find` an inner component... `shallow` will not work.

Comment: Please see the article below “Why I Always Use Shallow Rendering” by Anton Korzunov https://link.medium.com/T3u4Gik59U

Comment: I was also surpisied but `mount` also allows to search(`find()`) for custom components in tree just like they were not rendered. I guess it works thanks to `displayName` is injected somehow. So root cause(whatever it is) is not related to "`mount` vs `shallow`" diff.